# How can I paramaterize this Java generic?

Tags: java, generics, binary-tree

I am building a generic binary tree class in Java. I have not worked with generics too much before, so I do not know if I am doing this properly. Here is some code followed by my question:

```
public class Node<T> {

     T data;
     Node<T> left, right;
     //assume setters and getters
}


public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable <T>> {

       private Node<T> root;

       //assume typical setter/getter and insert, delete, etc methods

       public void inOrderTraversal() {

             //create instance of the inorder class here and call its traverse() method.
       }
}
//define a family of algorithms for preorder, inorder and postorder traversals
public interface BinaryTreeTraversal {

    public void traverse();

}
  //of course there will be a class for each type of traversal...
  //in order, pre order, post order
  class PreOrderTraversal extends BinaryTree implements BinaryTreeTraversal {

          public void traverse() { traverse(super.getRoot() ); }

          private void traverse(Node<T>) {
                   //the three lines of code this takes
          }

    }
```

So the problem I am having is that I keep getting errors saying missing type T, or unknown type T. So I tried changing the class heading it to

```
      class PreOrderTraversal extends BinaryTree<T> implements BinaryTreeTraversal { }
```

and

```
     class PreOrderTraversal extends BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<T>> implements BinaryTreeTraversal { }
```

and it did not work due to similar errors. What is a way that I can make this work? I am trying to apply a strategy pattern to the traversals. I just want to be able to have three types of traversals for any generic type. Any tips would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should review the [generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), specifically the section on subtyping.

Comment: Your PreOrderTraversal classdefinition should also be parameterized

Comment: PreOrderTraversal<T> extends BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<T>> implements BinaryTreeTraversal? I tried this and that does not work. I get a warning (not an error) saying BinaryTree should be parameterized when I do PreOrderTraversal<T> extends BinaryTree implements BinaryTreeTraversal, it is that acceptable style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private class PreOrderTraversal< T extends Comparable< T > > extends BinaryTree< T > implements BinaryTreeTraversal { ... }
```

For generic classes, the parameter and all its constraints go right next to the name of the class being defined.  Unfortunately, that syntax was not chosen for generic *methods*, where the generic type parameters and constraints precede the return type.

Answer (score 0):

your class `PreOrderTraversal` implements you generic class `BinaryTree` so here you need to define the type of T like

```
java
class PreOrderTraversal extends BinaryTree<Integer> implements BinaryTreeTraversal {

    private void traverse(Node<Integer>) {
    }

}
```

where `Integer` would by the type you are storing in the binary tree, now

Comment: Yes that works. Is there a way to not have to declare that way?

Comment: no ... what do you want to archive with not having to declare it? Saving lines of code? In that case Java might not be the best choice :)